# how to toggle between hide and show?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to identify elements by their tag name, but have trouble executing the toggle property using javascript. Perhaps I am not using toggle() correctly, please explain what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{
position: relative;
float:left
}
</style>
<script>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var hello=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
x.onclick=function(){
hello.toggle(
function(){hello.style.visibility:visible};
function(){hello.style.visibility:hidden};
)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the heck is `toggle`? The functions are invalid, with invalid syntax, and `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements!

Comment: `.toggle` is a jquery function.

Comment: You need to wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object to be able to use the jQuery functions.

Comment: What am I even looking at here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggle()` is a `jquery` function that shows hidden elements and vice versa.

To use it you need to add `jquery` in your `html`

e.g.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then with `jquery` you can add an event listener to the button:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('h1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Someone please format this. I'm on mobile and it's playing-up

Comment: cool thanks! i added document.ready in front of your function and it worked!